# Mongoose : search in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have this schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    providers : [{
            provider: { type: String, required: true },
            data : { type : String, unique: true }
        }]
});
```

For instance, an item can be :

```
providers: [{provider: "linkedin", data: "abcd"},
            {provider: "twitter", data: "efgh"}]
```

What I would like to search in Mongoose: provider == "linkedin" and data = "abcd".

Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to match multiple fields in the *same* element:

```
Model.find({providers: {$elemMatch: {provider: 'linkedin', data: 'abcd'}}})
```

The following would also work, but is more brittle as it would require an *exact* match of the element, with no extra fields and with the two fields in the same order.

```
Model.find({providers: {provider: 'linkedin', data: 'abcd'}})
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `$elemMatch` here instead of `db.w.find({providers:{provider:"linkedin", data:"abcd"}})` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux That would work, but is more brittle as it would require an _exact_ match of the element, with no extra fields and with the two fields in the same order.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was looking at [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-the-embedded-document) right now and just noticed that I've forgot about those limitations. Maybe worth mentioning that in your answer ?